# How I can disable block view from database D7

Tags: views, database

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

I have Last error, this error will be resolved when a user increase max allowad packet Im do it and set it 500MB, and Im clearing cach from DB, and Im restart a mysql server ..but not working

any way this error was trigger when Im try to save a block was creation in view, I think I know where is problem, its in filed in this block was add manually .. but now I need back to disable block to I can maintenance a problem, how I can do that ..

or there another way to resolve this problem ..

thanks alot

Comment: this way will be delete a block, I dont need to remove block, if I can disable block in view.. or mm I dont know >>

Comment: does the site run? are you able to view other views? do you get that error when you try to view the View Block you are attempting to disable?

Comment: deleting a block from the blocks table doesn't make it disappear from Views but it allows you to get to Views to edit/disable it.

Comment: thanks alot all, after Im research and try to resolve problem, Im find a problem, Im disable a view module and its not respoved a problem, so Im try to know why is error, the error was happend since its called many of local server, and each server have a mysql port defferance, So hte error was happend since of of these server has not changed max allowd packet... thanks alot all